# How to Placement a multiple page PDF file as artboard in Illustrator CC 2015

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, illustrator-scripting, cc-2015

I'm trying to Placement a PDF file with 10 pages and need to adjust each page in Illustrator CC 2015. How to Place with Link The PDF file in one single AI files with all artboard within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrator doesn't let you place a multi page pdf but there's a script that does, you can find it here: https://aiscripts.com/open-multipage-pdf/
I use it without issues with the last version of illustrator CC.